# Make a table out of array elements in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, multiple-columns

I want to achieve the following in BASH script

Current code

```
#!/bin/bash
Var=()
Var=(Title Album Song Rating 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13)
echo " ${Var[@]}"
```

Outputs:

```
Title    Album   Song    Rating  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
```

But what I want to achieve is a new line after every 4th element and in equal colums.

```
Title Album Song Rating

1      2     3   4   
5      6     7   8  
10    11     12  13
```

Comment: Do you have something against nine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `printf` for printing four elements per line, then align columns with `column`.

```
$ Var=(Title Album Song Rating 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)
$ printf '%s %s %s %s\n' "${Var[@]}" | column -t
Title  Album  Song  Rating
1      2      3     4
5      6      7     8
9      10     11    12
```

You can also use a simple function to generate the format string for `printf` if the number of columns is dynamic.

```
genfmt() {
  for ((i = 1; i < $1; i++)); do
    printf '%%s '
  done
  printf '%%s\\n'
}

printf "$(genfmt 4)" "${Var[@]}" | column -t
```

Comment: No advantage, but also `printf '%s\n' "${Var[@]}" | paste - - - -`